# can't set up speech-to-text GCP api

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform

I've been struggling to transcribe audio to text in Python. Here's what I've done so far:

1. Got a GCP billing account with a 90-day free trial
2. Enabled the Google Cloud speech-to-text API
3. Downloaded a JSON file and set it as an environment variable (always have to call `os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]='C:\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\google\Borster.json'` in Jupyter, otherwise when I do it with `set` in the cmd, the variable **disappears** when I reopen cmd)
4. I then noticed that I "**cannot import name 'enums' from 'google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1'**". So, the only thing I could do as a bypass was to replace the speech_v1p1beta1 folder with another one I found on the web that **did** have the `enums.py` file.
5. Then, I made a bucket called 'callsaudiofiles21' in Google Storage, but still couldn't access it, because it was giving me the **403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=i-enterprise-294210&projection=noAcl&prettyPrint=false: borster-659@i-enterprise-294210.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.list access to the Google Cloud project.**
6. I then did some research and it turns out I can't list the buckets because I haven't assigned the proper **role** to my account. So I did, [image] ...but still getting the same error.

I haven't been programming for too long so I'm very confused with this API and this whole Google Cloud platform in general. If there's anything else helpful I could share, please tell me. I've been struggling for 3 days but nothing going.

Answer (score 0):

The service account that you create does not have permission to your bucket. The error message states that the the `list` permission is missing.

The solution is to use the Google Cloud Console (or the CLI) and add the appropriate role to the service account.

[Granting, changing, and revoking access to resources](http://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access)

Select one of the Cloud Storage roles listed on this page:

[IAM roles for Cloud Storage](http://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles)

The service account will need **roles/storage.objectViewer**

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get it. I just went to the IAM page and added another bunch of [roles](https://i.postimg.cc/hG526Lnk/Screenshot-2020-11-02-142602.png), then created a new json file, but still got the same error. Does this mean what I'm doing is completely unrelated to the problem? The link you sent says to **ask my administrator** to assign me the role of **roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin**, but I understand neither who/what the **administrator** is, nor how to **ask** them for the role, nor the syntax of **roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin** and where to type it in

Comment: @BorisAdaev The service account that is missing the role is `borster-659@i-enterprise-294210.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. You do not need to download the JSON key file after modifying permissions. Why are you trying to add the role `roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin`? I specified the role to add. .If that does not work, you have a different problem.